# How would you feel about allowing questions in foreign languages and translation questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder how the community feels about:

- Allowing question about English but written in languages other than English?
- Allowing translations to (but not from) English?

I ask because EL&U is [almost the only language proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79712/should-we-do-anything-about-the-huge-language-mess-on-area51) that excluded those kinds of questions. The other language that have made it far on Area51 often allow translation questions and questions in other languages (sometimes only English, at other times more than just English).

I suspect that it's because of a bias in Stack Exchange's population. Most users who will visit Area51 will be fluent in English, on top of their own native language and thus unusually accepting or interested of those kinds of questions. I surmise the userbase of EL&U is likely to be more representative of how monolingual users stand on this question, which is why I'm curious of your answer.

So, I ask, how would you feel about allowing those type of questions?

Comment: Again, it seems as though people were voting this question down merely because they wanted to answer "no": what the heck is wrong with this question? It is a fine question. At least I am glad that this abuse of the voting function is not personal, because it seems Borror is appreciated on this website, as opposed to another user who got weird down-votes on his legitimate question.

Comment: On a side note, Borror's somewhat similar question, as referred to in his Question above, got 12 up-votes and a star. And two good answers.

Comment: @Cerberus: Downvotes on meta means you disagree. I'm not surprised that this got so many downvotes. I asked because I wanted to be sure that it would be unpopular.

Comment: @Dori: Ah I see, that explains it then. Thanks for the link; Shog's "The rules are different because Meta is... *kinda* misusing the SO engine" is what confused me. Even so, what impression does this make on newcomers? (I, apparently a newcomer, expected that the asker should add an answer and that this answer should get the downvotes...) Might not this practice put some people off? P.S. I knew it couldn't have been personal with Borror, because I sort of know him.

Comment: +1 Most people seems to not realize that English is a derivative from other languages and rather very recent one inseparable from its roots and can't be discussed in isolation from other cultures and languages

Comment: I must say I'm tempted to reject your premise that "the userbase of EL&U is likely to be more representative of how monolingual users stand on this question". There are *extremely* many non-native or bilingual speakers here, *especially* among the top users. Looking just through the top 100, I see native speakers of Italian, Hungarian, Turkish, Hindi, French, Portuguese, Spanish, German, Russian, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew...

Comment: @RegDwight: It's true the population of bilinguals and non-native speakers here is sizable, but it's at least 50% lower than the 100% from Area51. Hence the use of "more likely."

Answer (score 6):

While I hate to appear to be discouraging foreign languages anywhere, I have to say I would discourage them in English.SE. I say this knowing full well that I've responded to questions in a user's own native language in an effort to clarify a concept. But the point is, the user asked the question in English and the answers were almost entirely in English.

If we were to permit questions entirely in other languages, we would have to rename this site Babel.SE. This is, and I hope will remain, English.SE; and if that presents a problem for some people, I hope they will start their own SE sites: Polish-English.SE, Russian-English.SE, French-English.SE — hell, even Boston-English.SE or ValleyGirl-English.SE. Whatever.

We already bend over backwards to accommodate non-native speakers, provided they demonstrate a sincere desire to learn and make an attempt to communicate in the language they are trying to acquire. I don't see what more we can do without changing the essential nature of this site.

Comment: I think the best way to handle translation requests is with a free-for-all translation site, with tags to sort out the from- and to- languages, and with English as the lingua franca. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4306/translation

Comment: Thank you _so_ much for bending over backwards for all us non-native (English) speakers. The condescension I see displayed to "non-native speakers" by a small clique of "native speakers"/high-rep users(?) is what put me off this site, which is a shame since I was quite enjoying visiting it the first month I was here:-(

Comment: @Tragicomic: Well, no good deed goes unpunished. I'm not sure whether your misapprehension is deliberate or accidental, but it was not my intention to condescend. If you don't want the help of native speakers, and only care what non-native speakers think about the language, then good luck to you, wherever you go.

Comment: Upon reading my comment again, I see that it was sarcastic, and I apologize about that. I agree with you that questions on English.SE should be in English. Nor do I only care what non-native speakers think about the language. I just don't like the tone of the last paragraph of your answer (the bending over backwards etc.) I've just read some answers you've given to one of the users on this site, and I don't think you seem to mind bending over backwards.. :-)

Answer (score 3):

No to asking questions in other languages (other proposals usually allow that proposal's language and English as a *lingua franca* of Stack Exchange Network; this obviously doesn't apply with ELU).

Yes to allowing translation to English questions.  I'd really like to get a statement from the powers that be on this one; could we start allowing translation question to English?  It would make things more consistent.  It does seem unfair to me that on other language proposals, you are allowed to ask translation questions, but not on ELU.

Comment: The SE framework allows the community to define and maintain whatever local cultural norms a particular site has. It is _possible_ to allow translation questions to English, but I personally don't think it would match the current culture; any such question would be localized or of-topic because it requires minimum competency in both the source language and English (just like asking questions in non-English requires).

Comment: Yes but that's what we're going to be allowing on other SE sites.  Those who can't translate the phrase to English aren't obliged to answer the question.

Comment: I understand the "non-obligation" point, but even so, the questions will be too localized (only interesting useful to a very small minority if at all). Is the proposal to allow questions from -any language to English? That would swamp this site. I am basically supporting exactly what Robusto answered.

Comment: That is the proposal for the other language sites.  I disagree that they would swamp the site.

Comment: Like Robusto, I don't care for discouraging legitimate things like translation between languages. [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/) is centered on German, but English is considered well known enough to be a lingua franca there, so in say the German-Spanish section, discussinos can take place multilingually with German/English/Spansih, but French in that area would just be weird. For the proposed SE sites for 'anything to Y' translation, as much as I'd like to see it work, I think it'll have troubles.

Comment: @Jez: Actually following that logic, the one site that would have the best chance at making it because of numbers would be 'anything to English' as proposed. Now the question is whether to do that here or to have a separate site.

Comment: @Mitch Check out how the German beta is going.  There's the odd translation-to-German question but I don't think it's swamping the site.  stackoverflow.com receives orders of magnitude more questions.

Comment: @Jez: OK I think you convinced me, to your answer (no to questions in anything but English, but OK to allow translation to English of any other source language snippet. But now I think it'll still be difficult to convince others here (meta or main).

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this is our policy as it stands now:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Jeff, this policy seems to apply to non-language sites.  It makes sense that questions on German Language & Usage can be asked in German.

Comment: @jez NEIN! NEIN!

Answer (score -7):

I feel freaking bad (if to put it mildly)  and try to prove me otherwise hoping that this is correct answer.

And the rationale unders this is quite twisted since [my question on Russian proverb was just closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11182/help-me-to-translate-the-russian-proverb) but on English (American) saying or phrasal colloquial usage or meaning  of a phrase [taken from  an American novel was just plainly deleted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13354/is-sign-manual-language-for-the-deaf-a-language)

Comment: I would add a comment, but as you are _write-only_, you could not read it.